# Qt: How to remove holes / inside parts from a QPainterPath?

Tags: c++, qt, curve

I have a QPainterPath representing a capital Letter A. i want to add an offset outline to this Path. So i use

```
painterPath.setFillRule(Qt::WindingFill);
QPainterPathStroker stroker;
painterPath = stroker.createStroke(painterPath);
```

and then:

```
// Add additional inner lines created by QPainterPathStroker - this creates a border at the original glyph
painterPath -= originalPainterPath;
// Unite with the original area  - removes the border at the original glyph
painterPath += originalPainterPath;
```

This so far works pretty good. The red lines are created as a single QPainterPath element.
[image: 0ac76349-5d92-49e3-b0fb-13bec1a79d32-grafik.png]

But now i want tor remove the triangle inside the upper part of the created shape (marked with a green rectangle below):
[image]

I took several approaches here - all of them failed more or less.
The main problem seems to be, that all path functions (contains() / intersects()) only check weather something is in the (potentially filled) Path elements. Also setting setFillRule did not solve this.
Basically i want to remove everything which is inside the outline of the original shape - so that would be inside the black area below:
[image]

Comment: Could you share the code that draws the shape you have so far, so that you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The shape is drawn using QPainter drawPath. There is not much more.

Comment: Well, I cannot answer without knowing how (among several possibilities that all share the same result on screen) you defined your shape.

Comment: The shape is just an extraction of a Font Glyph - however the Font defines it. This images show one example of many.